# Convert timestamp data to date time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a DataFrame with a column containing timestamps and I would like to convert the column to date time in Python and save the file with a column containing the date and time. Here is the code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "time": [1465585763000, 1465586363000, 1465586963000, 
                  1465587563000, 1465588163000]})
    df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also work

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
d = {'time': [1465585763000, 1465586363000, 1465586963000,
              1465587563000, 1465588163000]}


print(d['time'])
new = [dt.fromtimestamp(x/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in d['time']]
pd.to_datetime(new)
```

Comment: I am not able to run your code in Jupyter. I got this error """ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing""" Would you please solve this?

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Comment: Ok. I fixed my response. Tell me if anything else goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

times = [
    1465585763000, 
    1465586363000, 
    1465586963000, 
    1465587563000, 
    1465588163000]

start_ts = dt.timestamp(dt(1970, 1, 1))
dates = [dt.fromtimestamp(time / 1000 + start_ts) for time in times]
pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I tried the code and I get this error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: Line 11: start_ts = dt.timestamp(dt(1970, 1, 1))